# Remover um elemento DOM tambem remove sua escuta?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collector

Eu já conheço o recurso do [Coletor de sujeira](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management#Garbage_collection).

Minha duvida é em relação a este recurso para o `addEventListener`.

#### Exemplo

```js
test.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
  test.className = 'active';
});

test.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
  test.className = '';
});

var i =0; setInterval(function(){
  count.innerHTML = ++i;
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function(){
  test.remove();
}, 5000);
```

```css
#test{
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
  background : #0000FF;
}

#test.active{
  background : #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<span id="count">0</span>

<div id="test">
</div>
```

#### Questão

- Ao fazer o `.remove()` o que ocorre com a escuta? ela fica com uma referencia nula?
- Antes de simplesmente remover o elemento eu necessito fazer `removeEventListener`? ou o GC vai capturar a escuta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remover do DOM só por si não retira os auscultadores de eventos. Um exemplo disso é que podemos manter uma referência ao elemento:

```js
const inicio = new Date();
const test = document.getElementById('test');
test.addEventListener('click', function(segs) {
  const agora = new Date();

  console.log('clique! passados', Math.round((agora - inicio) / 1000), 'segundos');
});

test.remove();
console.log(test.parentElement);
test.click();
setTimeout(() => test.click(), 10000);
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0000FF;
}

#test.active {
  background: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<span id="count">0</span>

<div id="test">
</div>
```

Quando à uns anos as SPA (single page aplication) começaram a ser populares e a mexer muito no DOM sem refresh da página surgiram problemas de fugas de memória. Algumas dessas fugas eram porque retirar um elemento do DOM não liberta tudo o que estava associado ao elemento.

É necessário remover também os auscultadores de evento passando a mesma função ao método `removeEventListener`.

No teu exemplo isso seria:

```js
const test = document.getElementById('test');
const adicionarClasse = function() {
  this.className = 'active';
}
const removerClasse = function() {
  this.className = '';
}
test.addEventListener('mouseover', adicionarClasse);
test.addEventListener('mouseout', removerClasse);

setTimeout(function() {
  test.removeEventListener('mouseover', adicionarClasse);
  test.removeEventListener('mouseout', removerClasse);
  test.remove();
}, 5000);
```

```css
#test {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0000FF;
}

#test.active {
  background: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

Relacionado: [um artigo na MDN sobre fugas de memória](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Extensions/Common_causes_of_memory_leaks_in_extensions) (<sub>em Inglês</sub>)

Comment: Quando dizes "retirar um elemento do DOM não liberta tudo o que estava associado ao elemento", é porque ainda existem outras referências ativas para esse elemento ? Caso não haja nenhuma seria tudo apanhado pelo GC não ?

Comment: @Isac sim, se não houver nada associado ao elemento nem referências dentro de escopos ativos o GC deve remover o elemento libertando a memória que ele tinha alocado.

Comment: @Sergio isso vai de encontro com minha pesquisa previa. [If a DOM Element is removed, are its listeners also removed from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory)

Comment: No caso de você estar fazendo o `click` logo em seguida a ação não poderia estar sendo feita pois o GC ainda não capturou o elemento?

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert desde que aja referências ao elemento o GC não remove. Juntei um exemplo onde espero 10s pelo clique depois de ter removido o elemento do DOM e ele funciona.